# Python web-scraping script returning nothing in Laravel variable

Tags: python, pandas, laravel, web-scraping

**This is my Python Script**

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/601.3.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.2 Safari/601.3.9'}

url = sys.argv[1]

response=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')
table = soup.find('table',{'id':'gsc_a_t'})

titles = []
for item in table.find_all(class_='gsc_a_at'):
  title = item.text
  titles.append(title)

print(titles)
```

**This is my Controller in Laravel.**
**After displaying $title it shows null**

```
$client = new Client();
$a = 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=';
$gscID = 'EnegzCwAAAAJ';
$b = '&hl=en&oi=ao';
$url = $a.$gscID.$b;

$title = shell_exec("python title.py $url");

dd($title);
```

**BUT When I run this python script it runs perfectly and shows the output**

```
import sys
import pandas as pd

url = sys.argv[1]
df = pd.read_html(url)

print(df[1])
```

> **I don't know what is wrong with this, I guess its because of the web scraping library BeautifulSoup used in it and the script is also running perfectly on Google Collab, I didn't find any resource on the internet which solves this problem, Any Help would be really appreciated**